# Conditionally creating directories from filenames in Gulp task

Tags: javascript, optimization, gulp, conditional-statements, pug

I have the following structure in my `source` directory:

```
|-source
  |-home.pug
  |-page1.pug
  |-page2.pug
```

I expect to get this in my `dest` directory:

```
|-dest
  |-index.html (former home.pug)
  |-page1/index.html (former page1.pug)
  |-page2/index.html (former page2.pug)
```

My Gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
  gzip = require('gulp-gzip'),
  htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
  path = require('path'),
  pug = require('gulp-pug'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('views', function() {

  gulp.src('source/!(home)*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      file.dirname = path.join(file.dirname, file.basename);
      file.basename = 'index';
      file.extname = '.html';
    }))
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'))

  gulp.src('source/home.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      file.basename = 'index';
      file.extname = '.html';
    }))
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'))
});
```

As you can see, there are two blocks using the same code on top and bottom. I would like to find a more optimal solution.

I added `gulp-if` and tried to implement if-else logic:

```
gulp.task('views', function() {
  gulp.src('source/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp-if(
     'home.pug',
     rename(function(file) {
      file.basename = 'index';
      file.extname = '.html';
    }),
     rename(function(file) {
      file.dirname = path.join(file.dirname, file.basename);
      file.basename = 'index';
      file.extname = '.html';
    })))
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'))
});
```

But this didn't work. Gulp created a redundant `dest/home/index.html` instead of just `dest/index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Gulpfile is just JavaScript. That means you can use regular `if (test) { }` statements as you would in any JavaScript program. No need for `gulp-if`.

This is even shorter than using `gulp-if` and gets you down to a single `rename()` operation:

```
gulp.task('views', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      if (file.basename !== 'home') {
        file.dirname = path.join(file.dirname, file.basename);
      }
      file.basename = 'index';
    }))
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'))
});
```

I also left out the `file.extname = '.html'` line. The `pug()` plugin already changes the extension from `.pug` to `.html`, so you don't need to do that yourself.